# Phoenix-framework : Mysql connection error on production

Tags: phoenix-framework

I am new to Phoenix and actually working on my first project in it.

When deploying the project on production server, I am getting a Database Connection error for mySql. For some reason, it is not considering the username/password values provided in config/prod.exs

```
import Config

config :g_plus, GPlusWeb.Repo,
  username: "root",
  password: "Somepassword",
  database: "db_name",
  hostname: "localhost",
  load_from_system_env: true,
  pool_size: 20
```

I also tried with environment variable (DATABSE_URL), but it is still not working.

```
ecto://root:Somepassword@localhost:3306/db_name
```

Am I missing any setting/config somewhere?

I couldn't find anything in Google search as well.
Most deployment guides are for apps without DB.

Comment: Could you share the error log please?

Comment: It just says the following: "[error] MyXQL.Connection (#PID<0.1468.0>) failed to connect: ** (MyXQL.Error) (1045) (ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR) Access denied for user 'apps'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".  But in prod.exs, I have provided username as "root" not "apps"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using GPlusWeb instead of just GPlus in the following line.

```
config :g_plus, GPlusWeb.Repo,
```

I changed it to `config :g_plus, GPlus.Repo,` and it worked.